# How to define a template method for a non-template class?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, methods, implementation

My compiler is not happy with the way I implement my template methods. It gives **tons** of error messages like "undefined type T" for these implementations.

This is my first method, it is implemented outside of the class block:

```
class VectorConvertor
{
    public:
        // ...
        template <class T>
        static void ReverseVectorElements(std::vector<T> & Vector);
        // ...
};

template <class T>
void VectorConvertor::ReverseVectorElements(std::vector<T> & Vector)
{
    std::vector<T>::size_type size = Vector.size();
    T swap;
    for (std::vector<T>::size_type i=0; i<size/2; i++)
    {
        swap = Vector.at(i);
        Vector.at(i) = Vector.at(size-1-i);
        Vector.at(size-1-i) = swap;
    }
}
```

Another one is this; this time the method is implemented inside the class:

```
class ElementaryMath
{
    public:
        // ...
        template <class T> static char sign(T num)
        {
            return (num >= static_cast<T>(0)) ? static_cast<char>(+1) : static_cast<char>(-1);
        }
        // ...
}
```

Is there anything wrong with my code, or is this just a problem with the compiler itself?

IDE & Compiler: Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code looks OK to me. But there is one thing that got in my mind. Can you please check if the function "sign" is defined before? Simply hover your mouse on it. C runtime library implements some of its functions using the "#define" keyword and because of that you can't define a function with that same name afterwards.

Comment: @hkBattousai: max and min macros in the winapi are a constant source of headaches.  There's a special config macro to define (best to do in the project settings) to prevent the winapi from creating them; see, for example, http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/101300/std-numeric-limits-min-std-numeric-limits-max-and-min-max-macros.  (Made more sense before you deleted your comment, but I'm leaving this here because I think it still applies.)

Comment: Oh, you hit the spot, really. Not the function "sign()" was, but another one (the very first compiler error), "max()" was defined the same way you said. I undefined it as below and now there is no compiler errors. >> `#ifdef max --- #undef max --- #end`

Answer (score 4):

You're missing some `typename`s and semicolons, but otherwise, the code seems OK. IMHO it's time to file a bug if it still doesn't work.

BTW, the swapping code would be better done with `std::swap`.

Comment: In addition to using std::swap (which would be used as {using std::swap; swap(a, b);}) the whole loop can be replaced by  std::swap_ranges(Vector.begin(), Vector.begin()+Vector.size()/2, Vector.rbegin())

Comment: @Grizzly well if all he wants to do is reverse he can just std::reverse

Comment: @CashCow: iter_swap has its roots in pre-standard C++ and there's no reason to use it today.

Answer (score 1):

Your code compiles without error on VS2005 (apart from a missing semicolon at the end of the definition of ElementaryMath) so you may be looking at a compiler bug.

VS2010 SP1 is available in beta [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=11ea69cb-cf12-4842-a3d7-b32a1e5642e2&displaylang=en). Might help, but obviously its beta...

Comment: The answers mentioning 'typename' are talking about dependent types, not the template parameter list.

Comment: Totally incorrect answer but I'm done with downvoting for today.

Comment: @FredNurk Thanks, I didn't realise that. I've removed the misleading part about typename.

Answer (score 1):

typename here:

```
template <class T>
void VectorConvertor::ReverseVectorElements(std::vector<T> & Vector)
{
    typename std::vector<T>::size_type size = Vector.size();
    T swap;
    for (typename std::vector<T>::size_type i=0; i<size/2; i++)
    {
        swap = Vector.at(i);
        Vector.at(i) = Vector.at(size-1-i);
        Vector.at(size-1-i) = swap;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class VectorConvertor
{
    public:
    // ...
    template <typename T>
    static void ReverseVectorElements(std::vector<T> & Vector);
};

template <typename T>
void VectorConvertor::ReverseVectorElements(std::vector<T> & Vector)
{
    std::vector<T>::size_type size = Vector.size();
    T swap;
    for (std::vector<T>::size_type i=0; i<size/2; i++)
    {
        swap = Vector.at(i);
        Vector.at(i) = Vector.at(size-1-i);
        Vector.at(size-1-i) = swap;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector <int> i(10,0);

    VectorConvertor obj;   // Since your class isn't a template, template parameter
                           // isn't required for a class template instantiation.
                           // However, if your class was a template class, template-
                           // parameter must have been required for a class template
                           // instantiation.

    obj.ReverseVectorElements(i);  // Equal to obj.ReverseVectorElements<int>(i);
                                   // Based on type of i, compiler can instantiate a 
                                   // template function by default.
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Did you [try compiling](http://codepad.org/QQOi7sCT) this?  (Note that some versions of msvc get dependent names wrong.)

Comment: @Fred Nurk : Do you mean to say that it's the issue with the compiler or the way I programmed is wrong ? Please provide information on what is wrong in preventing myself being wrong again :)

Comment: Both; see the link I gave above, http://codepad.org/QQOi7sCT, and read up on dependent names (both in other answers here and elsewhere).